# Salesforce DX push failed to scratch org with error parsing package.xml-meta.xml file

Tags: salesforcedx, vs-code, package.xml, push

After created a scratch org, I pushed my visualforce page and got error:

> Error  force-app\package.xml-meta.xml  Error parsing file: Element {http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata}types invalid at this location in type EmailServicesFunction (4:12)
> ERROR running force:source:push:  Push failed.

[image]

In apex class, I use Messaging.sendEmail api to send a Messaging.SingleEmailMessage with the custom email template.

Does anyone meet the same error? Is there anyway to debug this case?

Any help would be much appreciated thanks!

Comment: How did you generate the [SFDX project](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_ws_create_new.htm), the structure of folder doesn't look right.

Comment: @Raul Project created by command: 
> sfdx force:project:create --projectname seminardemo --defaultpackagedir force-app

Comment: Do you plan to use `EmailServicesFunction` in your project? Can you confirm if the manifest file contains the `EmailServicesFunction` type?

Comment: @TSmith In manifest file has no input directly EmailServicesFunction type but in Apex class I use Messaging.sendEmail api to send a Messaging.SingleEmailMessage, I just guess that's why sfdx require EmailServicesFunction.